# Microsoft Project 2010 - How to set resource units based-on date of week?

Tags: microsoft-project, project-management

I want to set units for resource `WorkerA` at Tue and Thu are 80%; and 94% for Mon, Wed, Fri.
This rules apply for all time of project, so I cannot set value by manual, task by task. How to implement this rule in one-time?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Microsoft Project 2010. The best you could achieve would be to use two separate resources with different availabilities and working days. There is nothing to stop you using two separate resources to mean one individual person, though it would require some manual reconciliation and reporting of resource usage to combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not bother with max units in your case.  I suggest altering the resources work week calendar. On Tuesday and Thursday alter the resource's calendar so s/he only works 6 hours per day and on Mon, Wed, Friday - set the calendar for 7.5 hours per day.